# Error when using the "Select-Object" cmdlet from C# to Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to use the "Select-Object" cmdlet in C# in order to get a specific value from a "PSMemberInfo" object in powershell.

The object in question is as follows:

`"EmailAddresses": {dir: dirAddress, smtp: address1, smtp: address2}.`

If i run the following command in powershell i get the value of "dir":

`Get-RemoteMailbox *identity* | Select-Object @{Name='EmailAddresses';Expression={($_.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike 'dir*'} | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'dir:',''}) -join ','}}`

I need to do the same task but from a C# runspace. I tried doing the following:

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{

        string filter = "Select-Object @{{Name=\"EmailAddresses\";Expression={{($_.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {{$_ -clike \"dir*\"}} | ForEach-Object 
{{$_ -replace \"dir:\",\"\"}}) -join \",\"}}}";

        ps.Runspace = Runspace;
        ps.AddCommand("Get-RemoteMailbox")
        .AddParameter("Identity", identity)
        .AddCommand(filter);
}
```

But i get the following error:

"The term 'Select-Object @{Name='EmailAddresses';Expression={($*.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {$* -clike 'dir*'} | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'dir:',''}) -join ','}}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Basically it's not recognizing the same exact command that i just executed in the exchange management shell.

Please send help.

Comment: Side note: it's typically not needed to execute a PowerShell cmdlet, especially one delivered in Windows, from within C#. Such information can be obtained/manipulated using C# or .Net APIs directly.

Answer (score 0):

The argument for [`.AddCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addcommand?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0) must be an actual command, you can use [`.AddArgument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addargument?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0) instead in this case to pass in the [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3#select-object) to `Select-Object`:

```
using (Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    rs.Open();
    ps.Runspace = rs;

    ScriptBlock sb = ScriptBlock.Create(@"
        $mails = $_.EmailAddresses |
            Where-Object { $_ -clike 'dir*' } |
            ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'dir:' }

        $mails -join ','");


    ps.AddCommand("Get-RemoteMailbox")
        .AddParameter("Identity", identity)
        .AddCommand("Select-Object")
        .AddArgument(new Hashtable
        {
            { "Name", "EmailAddresses" },
            { "Expression", sb }
        });

    // more code here
}
```

Another perhaps easier alternative is to use [`.AddScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0):

```
using (Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    rs.Open();
    ps.Runspace = rs;
    ps.AddScript(@"
        param($identity)

        $expression = {
            $mails = $_.EmailAddresses |
                Where-Object { $_ -clike 'dir*' } |
                ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'dir:' }

            $mails -join ','
        }

        Get-RemoteMailbox $identity |
            Select-Object @{ N = 'EmailAddresses'; E = $expression }
    ").AddParameter("identity", identity);

    // more code here
}
```